# Where afetando apenas um campo no select

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, sql-select

Bom dia, como faço pra minha cláusula where afetar apenas um(1) campo na minha pesquisa? Por exemplo:

```
$query = DB::table('proventosdesc as proven')
            ->join('calculo_rh as calc', 'proven.pessoaId', '=', 'calc.pessoaId')
            ->join('pessoa', 'calc.pessoaId', '=', 'pessoa.id')
            ->select('pessoa.nome as a', 'calc.cargo as b', 'calc.departamento as c',
                    DB::raw("SUM(proven.valor) as d"))
            ->groupby('proven.pessoaId');
```

Quero deixar uma condição apenas pro último campo "proven.valor" impondo apenas o retorno dos tipo P, séria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$query = DB::table('proventosdesc as proven')
            ->join('calculo_rh as calc', 'proven.pessoaId', '=', 'calc.pessoaId')
            ->join('pessoa', 'calc.pessoaId', '=', 'pessoa.id')
            ->select('pessoa.nome as a', 'calc.cargo as b', 'calc.departamento as c',
                    DB::raw("SUM(proven.valor) as d")->where('proven.tipo, '=', 'P')
            ->groupby('proven.pessoaId');
```

Desse jeito não funciona, passando o where internamente no campo determinado.

Não queria que essa condição afetasse todo o select mas sim apenas esse ultimo campo, pois vou precisar fazer outra condição do mesmo jeito para um outro campo do mesmo select...
Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?
Estou disposto a oferecer qualquer informaçao caso não ficou claro a dúvida !

Comment: Quer apenas a ultima linha returnada dessa query?

Comment: Não, quero que meu select inteiro funcione, mas com condições apenas para um campo e não pro select inteiro, se eu colocasse a cláusula where no final, antes ou depois do groupby funcionaria perfeitamente, mas dai pegaria todo o select, quero que funcione apenas pro último campo.

Comment: Quer agarrar tudo mas depois tratar o ultimo item do array à parte, já com php? Seria como eu faria

Comment: Editei lá, muito obrigado Miguel !

Comment: Você deve responder à sua própria pergunta e colocar aceite quando puder. Assim fica mais facil para outros colegas identificarem logo a solução nesta página. Parabéns

Answer (score 1):

Consegui, o jeito de resolver é fazendo outro select internamente, ficando assim:

```
->select('pessoa.nome as a', 'calc.cargo as b', 'calc.departamento as c',
                    DB::raw("(Select SUM(valor) From proventosdesc where pessoaId = calc.pessoaId and tipo = 'P') as d"))
            ->groupby('proven.pessoaId');
```